# Override list method in Django rest ViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In a Django Rest Framework ViewSet I have an overrided list()

```
class TicketViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
     def_list():
        make_my_checks()
        things_copied_from_parent()
```

Since the list() has many lines of code and I must make checks in every ViewSet, how can I make this checks and return the overrided method? A thing like:

```
def_list():
    make_my_checks()
    super(list())
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there!!!

```
class TicketViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        make_my_checks()  # your custom checks
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)  # you should return them
```